# Merging/spanning header or cells in DataGrid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to merge cells across columns or header cells (whatever is easier)of my DataGrid dynamically. I need to have a header that spans multiple columns. I've read a articles on merging cells and header cells but all solutions hard code column names in XAML. My problem is that the span of the header and how many spanned headers I will have is dictated by what data comes back from the database. Any ideas? Thanks.